# How can I test an apex for loop?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have an apex class where i have written a FOR loop. I need to write test class to cover the for loop.

My for loop will be

```
for(i=1; i<10; i++)
{
   if(i=1)
   {
       do something;
    }
    if(i=2)
    {
       do something;
    }
}
```

Please suggest me how to cover this code in my test class.

Comment: as @sunny has specified in the answer, if you are calling the method which has the for loop it should cover the for loop. It would be helpful for us if you post the test code as well as your class code to debug the issue

Comment: I have posted my code in the discussion board too.. The link is http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/test-class-for-inner-class/td-p/715953                My code is covering only 23% and the FOR loop is not getting covered..

Answer (score 2):

If you have written that for loop inside any method, try to call that method which will automatically(Most of the extent) cover code inside that loop.

Comment: I called my method in the test class but still the code is not getting covered for my FOR loop...